# Preview file when doing ctrl+tab in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I come from Sublime Text and in it we can always preview the file content while changing tabs, so we can be sure we switch to the one we want or otherwise we keep `ctrl` pressed and press multiple times on `tab` until we find the file we want.

By default Visual Code won't show you the content and instead will only show the "Rencently opened" where we can read the file names in our history of opened files.

Any way to change that so we can see the content of the file we are about to switch to?

My current bindings to emulate the Sublime Text behaviour is following:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.openPreviousEditorFromHistory"
},

{ 
    "key": "ctrl+tab", 
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext", "when": "inQuickOpen" 
},
```

Comment: Rebind it to `workbench.action.nextEditor` & `workbench.action.previousEditor`?

Comment: But this way they don't navigate as I want. I want them to work like in Sublime Text, which is basically moving on the history tabs. I've updated my question with my current bindings.